# Error with Spring Security and ehcache

Tags: spring-security, ehcache

I have a Spring based application that runs on tomcat. The application is configured using XML. When I added POM dependencies for Spring Security, I get some errors that I am unable to troubleshoot. Please help -

Here are the POM dependencies added -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here are the errors -

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.expression.IntegrationEvaluationContextAwareBeanPostProcessor

Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor

Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut

Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl

Error creating bean with name 'ehCacheManager' defined in file ....appcontext-servlet.xml

Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
```

Comment: Can you see the root cause of the errors in the log?

Comment: Indeed, without more information about why the different bean creations fail, hard to help.